# Get messages count in queue using spring jms

Tags: spring

I am using Jboss, hornetQ and spring JMS. I would like to get the count of messages in queue. is it any possibility to get the message count using spring jms api? If it is possible, please give me your suggestions. Otherwise how to achive this?

Thanks-
vasu

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve so using JMX.

- [Configuring Message Counters](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/management.html#management.message-counters)
- [Message Counter Example](https://github.com/krukow/stomple/blob/master/hornetq/examples/jms/message-counters/src/org/hornetq/jms/example/MessageCounterExample.java)